# Testing nodejs harmony generator method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, ecmascript-harmony, chai

Suppose you have the following JS function:

```js
function YourProxy($orm, $usr) {

     this.addToDB = function(obj) {
     /* Do some validation on obj */
        return function(callback){
            var oo = $orm.createNew(obj);
            oo.save(options, function(err,ok){
                if(err) callback(err);
                callback(null,ok);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

which you can use on node.js with ES6 generators to wait for that operation to happen with something like:

```
function *(){
    var yourProxy = new YourProxy();
    try {
        var result = yield yourProxy.addToDB(anObject);
    } catch(e) { 
        /* Something went wrong sync. Here you have err from save's callback */
    }
    /* result contains ok, the one from save's callback */
}
```

To test that I've done something like this, using mocha and sinon (and mocha-sinon):

```js
describe('addToDB', function(){
    it('adds the object to the db', function(){
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        myProxy.addToDB(anObject)(callback);
        expect( callback ).to.be.calledOnce;
    });
 });
```

but all I got is that the callback is never called because addToDB() exits before the save's callback gets called.

How would you test that?

Comment: did you call mocha with harmony flags?

Comment: Of course! Or else I would have got a rant stating that yield is "an ancient word that means we are what we are because we don't like Java" :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `co-mocha` and yield the generator as you did it in your example.

```
describe('addToDB', function(){
    it('adds the object to the db', function* (){
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        yield myProxy.addToDB(anObject)(callback);
        expect( callback ).to.be.calledOnce;
    });
 });
```

Comment: This won't work.  co-mocha monkey-patches the mocha Runnable (before, beforeEach, after, afterEach, and it).  "describe" is not a Runnable.  If you give describe a generator it will not execute anything inside of that generator (I learned this the hard way).  So just move the * to  the function in the "it" and it will work.

Comment: Correct, I haven't tested the code. I've edited now. Thanks.